# How do I group my certain rows into a new heading in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix visual with a list of KPI's taken from different tables

Sample Matrix Data visual - ABCDEF are KPIS

```
             Australia   NZ   India  Korea  China
   
A   
B   
C   
D   
E   
F
```

I have to add another column to the left of the A,B,C etc called as "Pillar" which will be grouping these existing kpis into further bigger groups

Expected Output :

```
                 Australia   NZ   India  Korea  China
       
 
  Dog   A   
  Cat   B   
  Cat   C   
  Bird  D   
  Bird  E   
  Bird  F   
  Bird  G
```

I have to create this new column Pillar and put in my matrix visual.

Challenges I am facing are:

1. I do not have the list of KPI's in one Table, so do I add this new column in all my tables by going into data transformation?

How do I achieve this?

Comment: requirement not that clear. show your actual table structure with sample data and then show your expected output from them.

Comment: Okay, i will edit the question

Comment: You are showing your Matrix details which is output. can you show the input table (database table) structure with sample data?

Comment: My each KPI  is coming from different table. I have joined different tables from the master table thru relationships. 
i am taking 1 or 2 kpis from 1 table , there are about 15 tables.